# Symfony form dummy errors

Tags: error-handling, symfony, symfony-forms

In a Symfony form, how could I add some dummy errors to test how errors are printed ?

I would like to test all errors : global (`{{ form_errors(form) }}`) and widget-specific (`{{ form_row(form.tags) }}`)

I've searched throught all [these documentation links](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#learn-more) and didn't find anything.

I also looked about [validators](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html) but nothing seems to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you are (in your controller):

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;

$form->get('yourAttribute')->addError( new FormError('your error message'));
```

Comment: Thanks ! And for global errors, just write `$form->addError(...)`

Comment: do you know how to add error to a Collection entry ?

Comment: Maybe you are asking too much, my friend ;-D.
No, I am kidding, I don't know the answer, but maybe you can take a look to the Form interface. 
I think you have to $form->get('collectionAttribute'), this will return you the child form of the collection.

Edit: and after play with some methods to reach your goal

Comment: I Am pretty sure this is something like 
$form->get('collectionAttribute')->get( idOfYourEntity or LineOfCollection)->get('yourEntityAttribute')->addError ...

If you var_dump each step I am sure you will get the answer